# Skipping x rows in an iterable of a subset of a dataframe

Tags: python, loops, indexing, iterator, python-itertools

I have a dataframe with a total number of `154529` rows through which I iterate by grouping it based on one of its columns.

During my iteration I look for a specific correlating row `y` with regards to the current row `x` (the one, the iterable is currently at). As soon as I found the row `y`, I want to skip the iteration until one row/index **after** row `y`.

To do so, I'm using the `next(islice(...))` functionality. However, the `islice` method always skips to the wrong index. My assumption is, that this is because of my iteration on subsets only but the indices are still relative to the whole dataframe.

I already tried to solve my problem b< applying `reset_index()` on the sub-dataframe, but as I need the original indices for some assignments that are done during the looping, this approach doesn't work.
Can anybody help me with the finding of the correct *Start* parameter for the `islice()` method?

Here are some example indices for deeper investigations. (I wasn't able to find a pattern in the offsets of the actual new indices.)
[image: deep dive on indices]

And here is my code

```
from itertools import islice

case_started = False

for session_id, session_df in labeled_data.groupby('SessionId'):
    
    session_iterations = session_df.iterrows()
   
    start_end_pairs = [] #store all start-end-pairs for each session
    next_start_index = ''

    for index, row in session_iterations:
        # doing stuff to find row y 
        # doing some assignemnts with row y index and current row index

        start_end_pairs.append((index, row_y))
        next_start_index = case_end + 1
        if next_start_index < session_df.index[-1]:   
                skip = case_end - index #skipping relative to current index
                next(islice(session_iterations, skip, None), 'Stop') #skipping to next start index
            else:
                break
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of help or hints!

Comment: what's the value of `case_end`?

Comment: You can still access the old index after calling `reset_index()` because it is transformed to a column named `"index"` by default.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the second argument to `islice`, try setting it to `skip`.

Example:

```
dataset['C'] = np.arange(len(dataset)) # just to validate iterator does not break
rowiter = dataset.iterrows()
for a, b in rowiter:
  print("idx", a, "row number", b.C)
  if a % 5 == 0:
    next(islice(rowiter, 4, 4), None) # skipping the next four rows
  if a > 10:
    break
```

Results in:

```
idx 0 row number 0.0
idx 5 row number 5.0
idx 10 row number 10.0
idx 15 row number 15.0
```

Which is the expected output.